# command "init 1" freezes computer

Tags: init, telinit

I'm taking a Beginners Administration for Linux class, and one of the things we are learning is how to change "runlevel" in order to optimize efficiency and security of a server. However, when I run the command "init 1" or "telinit 1" it brings my computer to the Ubuntu loading screen, looks like it is loading something, and then freezes.

I have tried this with the same results on both my dedicated desktop and on a separate computer through a virtual machine.

Am I doing something wrong? I am a borderline n00b so I understand it is probable I am missing something obvious.

Comment: did you try pressing alt-f2 for instance, to go to a new virtual console?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, single user mode has not been a priority in Ubuntu. There is a bug tag for issues related to using runlevel 1, and as you can see there are quite a few of them:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?field.tag=runlevel1

Its likely that you have run into one of these or an unknown issue. I recommend reporting a bug with the tag `runlevel1`.